# Google Cloud SSh from one instance to another

Tags: ssh, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform, private-key, gcloud

I have been trying to ssh from one google cloud instance to another.   I am able to SSH from my local machine which the host OS is windows and the VM OS which is Ubuntu.

I am running the commands straight from the website.

1.

```
me@local:~$ eval `ssh-agent`
```

2.

```
me@local:~$ ssh-add ~/.ssh/google_compute_engine
```

3.

```
gcloud compute ssh --ssh-flag="-A" INSTANCE
```

The error I am getting is

ERROR: (gcloud.compute) Invalid choice: 'ssh-flag=-A'.

Everything I see on internet is how to SSH into the VM but not how to SSH from one VM to another.

Comment: Straight from which website?

Comment: The google compute guide attempted to walk through this but their example must be deprecated or something --- https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/connecting-to-instance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can still do this, with `gcloud` version 97.0.0:

```
> gcloud compute ssh --ssh-flag="-A" --zone=us-central1-f user@ssh-test
Warning: Permanently added '104.197.77.90' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.

The programs included with the Debian GNU/Linux system are free software;
the exact distribution terms for each program are described in the
individual files in /usr/share/doc/*/copyright.

Debian GNU/Linux comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY, to the extent
permitted by applicable law.
user@ssh-test:~$
```

Are you sure the command in #3 is copied correctly?

Comment: It worked sir.  That error I am getting is kind of misleading, I needed to change a different part of that statement than the 'A' flag. Thanks!

Comment: It worked but I still can't ssh from one instance to another.  I'm getting a 'Permission denied (publickey)'

Comment: Check the serial port output of the instance you're trying to SSH into.

Comment: I just cant daisy chain ssh but I guess thats ok and I shouldn't need to

Answer (score 1):

From your **first instance** do:

```
gcloud auth login
```

and you will be given a link, paste that into your browser, then login with the account of your **second instance**.
You will then get a **key** paste that in your **first instance** terminal.